# Why does jQuery.post end up in PHP's $_POST, and my vanilla JS post does not?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm using vanilla JavaScript to send a AJAX post request with JSON data:

```js
xhr.open(method, url,true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

The headers look good, but in PHP `$_POST` is empty. There are several related questions on SO about this, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php), but they all suggest using:

```php
json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))
```

However, if I use `jQuery.post` my variables end up in `$_POST`, so it must be possible. My question is *how?* What might I be doing wrong? Or what could I change?

Comment: If you want to use `$_POST` then you need to send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header, not `application/json`.

Comment: I think the best thing to do is to send it as JSON, and use `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))` instead of $_POST. That's really just a preference, but in my opinion, it makes more sense to send JSON because it's much more expressive than $POST variables.

Comment: I might do that for different situations @Juan Mendes, but I'm using the PHP framework Slim which is not picking up my post variables in a $app->post handler if I use json, so that's why I was asking how to get normal $_POST variables and still use json encoding to send data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That happens because jQuery converts the data you pass in to a string in the format of a form, with a  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header, which is something PHP recognizes and correctly creates the `$_POST` superglobal from.

Your native XMLHttpRequest sends the data as a string in JSON format with the `application/json` header, which PHP does not recognize as form data, and does not create a `$_POST` array from.

In modern browsers you can use [**`formData`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) to create valid form data that can be sent with ajax and recognized by PHP

Comment: I think it would be helpful to explain that the OP is sending the JSON as the body of the HTTP request whereas jQuery is converting the object into `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, it's not sending JSON

Comment: @adeneo, ah ok! so, I switched back to ```application/x-www-form-urlencoded``` now, and send my data as payload using ```Url.urlEncode(data)```, now I see them in ```$_POST``` however then the objects I try to send end up as the string ```[object Object]```. So should I then ```JSON.stringify``` the individual values of the data I wish to send?

Comment: @Flion That is correct, right now you're you're sending the result of    `Object.toString()` which is called internally because the function requires a string